# How to debug an incorrect binding

Tags: objective-c, debugging, core-data, interface-builder

I got the error `cannot create BOOL from object` with CoreData. I read a lot of questions on this, all leading to the same conclusion: an incorrect binding in IB.
Is there a way I could for example list all bindings, or is there a utility app that checks the type of the bindings? Perhaps catch the error, or implement a method that gets called when this happens so I can retrieve the name of the bound object? I'd rather solve it myself than have someone nice analyse my `.xib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been pulling my hair out over this. In a XIB with dozens or potentially hundreds of bindings it's almost impossible to find out where this is coming from. But I finally found a way to narrow it down a bit.

I just set a symbolic break point on

```
-[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context]
```

and configure it as follows

- Action: Debugger Command, Enter `po $rdi` as the command to execute. This will print out *self* (i.e. the NSValueBinder description) every time the break point is hit. This (`$rdi`) is for x86_64, for other architectures see [this article](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/02/04/inspecting-obj-c-parameters-in-gdb/).
- Check *Automatically continue after evaluating*

Now when I run the program I get a bunch of binding related logs in the console that should look something like this:

```
$7 = 4301564448 <NSTextValueBinder: 0x10064aa20>{object: <NSTextFieldCell: 0x10061eea0>, bindings: value=selection.myProperty}
```

The last one is obviously the one that throws the exception. I can usually figure out which view it is from the bindings value directly or from some of the other bindings that are established before the error occurs. Another thing that helps, is examining the `superview`  or `controlView` of the offending object, e.g. with `po [0x10061eea0 controlView]` in the example above.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not such a debugger hero, so I would never have thought of that!

Comment: I can't get this to work, do you know of any common issues that could be causing this?  I copy pasted directly the symbol you provided